# Javascript IFrame/designmode and onkeydown event question

Tags: javascript

Apologize if this is answered already.  Went through some of the related questions and google, but ultimately failed to see why this isn't working.

My code is as follows

```
<iframe id="editor"></iframe>

editorWindow = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow;
isCtrlDown = false;

function loadEditor()
{
    editorWindow.document.designMode = "on";
    editorWindow.document.onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.which == 91) isCtrlDown = false;
    }
    editorWindow.document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
}

function handleKeyDown(e)
{
    if (e.which == 91) isCtrlDown = true;
    if (e.which == 66 && isCtrlDown) editFont('bold');
    if (e.which == 73 && isCtrlDown) editFont('italic');
}

function editFont(a,b)
{
    editorWindow.document.execCommand(a,false,b);
    editorWindow.focus();
}
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome, but the keyboard shortcuts do not work in Firefox.  In fact, in Firefox it does not seem to register the events for keyup/keydown at all.

Am I doing something grossly wrong here that is mucking up Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For editable documents, you need to use `addEventListener` to attach key events rather than DOM0 event handler properties:

```
editorWindow.document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false);
```

If you care about IE 6-8, you will need to test for the existence `addEventListener` and add the `attachEvent` equivalent if it is missing.

Comment: Thanks. You can accept an answer by clicking the green tick to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
editorWindow = document.getElementById('editor').frameElement;
```

I'm not sure this will solve the issue, it may also be:

```
editorWindow = document.getElementById('editor').contentDocument;
```

Or even possibly:

```
editorWindow = document.getElementById('editor').frameElement.contentDocument;
```

One thing you can do is put the entire string in a try statement to catch any errors and see if the content is being grabbed from within the iframe.

```
try { editorWindow = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow; } catch(e) { alert(e) };
```

The only other thought I have is that you're typing into a textbox which is within an iframe, and you may possibly have to add the onkeydown event to that specific item, such as:

```
var editorWindow = document.getElementById('editor').contentDocument;
var textbox = editorWindow.getElementById('my_textbox');

function loadEditor()
{
editorWindow.document.designMode = "on";
textbox.onkeydown = function(e) {
    alert('hello there');
}
}
```

I hope one of these is the solution. I often find when it comes to cross-platform functionality it often boils down to a little trial and error.

Good Luck!

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Might just be something weird with Firefox's implementation or something special for Chromes.  I ended up using AddEventListener like someone suggested above.  Thanks for your help though.